# Chromium Doesn't want to run Java applets

Tags: java, chromium

I can run the Java test page [here](http://www.java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp) in firefox, and it works fine. When I open it in chromium, it just stays white, and no "java" instance is started. Minecraft works fine. The screen shot was taken whil openjdk-6 was installed.

I have tried the following:

*Clearing Chromium preferences data (rm -rfv ~/.config/chromium)

*Purging and re installing all java-related packages, including the icedtea plugin.

*Using Openjdk-7 and 6

I am currently running Chromium 18 (the latest update)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling chromium itself ? (with/without purge)

Comment: No, shall do, along with deleting user data...

Comment: Purged, deleted user data (again), re-installed, changed nothing.

Comment: Install Java Tea for Ubuntu

Comment: @BigGenius How would I do that?

Comment: You can google linux java for browser. And there it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to build the icedtea package from 12.10.
First I downloaded

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/icedtea-web_1.2-2ubuntu3.debian.tar.gz
and

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/icedtea-web_1.2.orig.tar.gz

Then extracted the orig.tgz file into a build folder, and the debian.tgz into the folder the previous extraction created (icedtea-web-1.2).

Then I cd'ed into the icedtea-web-1.2 folder and ran

```
dpkg-buildpackage-uc -b
```

As necessary, I installed dependencies, and then I had several packages in the build folder. I ran

```
sudo dpkg -i *7-plugin* *netx*
```

(With wildcards around

to install the necessary files.

Answer (score 0):

This is bug 1025553.  I'll be uploading this to proposed Monday and it should go out to everyone about a week after that.  You can subscribe to the bug to find out when it's available for testing and how to enable the test repositories.